# updating multiple columns to blank based flag true otherwise keep column values as it is pyspark

Tags: pyspark

> Here df contains the other column and values in addition to column mentioned in the col_list but we need to update only the column mentioned in col_list based flag true but below not working as excepted.

```
col_list = ['age','label','test','length','work','least']

for i in col_list:
    test = df.withColumn(i, when(df.flag != True, df[i]).otherwise(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace df.withColumn with test.withColumn to update your test df each time. Right now it's only makes the last col.

```
test_df = df
for i in col_list:
    test_df = test_df.withColumn(i, F.when(df.flag != True, df[i]).otherwise(''))
```

Comment: with this approach it is making all the columns blank instead for specific flag blank